# RadioButtonList with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button, radio-group

I need a RadioButtonList with a bunch of on/off choices similar to the CheckBoxList. I need it to translate to an on/off for each option, but Knockout resolves a group of radio buttons down to one value. Suggestions?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DPnBE/2/

Comment: CITIZEN'S ARREST. This is actually a misuse of the radio button metaphor. Only one radio button of the set should be active at any one time -- the choices are mutually exclusive, like a vintage car radio. You cannot listen to more than one station simultaneously, right? What makes GUI conventions succeed is their conventionality.

Comment: "CITIZEN'S ARREST" that's funny. The radio button UI isn't affected, just the underlying data. To the user, it still looks and works as expected. Take a look at the example jsFiddle on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a custom binding. You could probably get rid of the for loop by storing the previously selected item somewhere. Then you just have to select and unselect 2 items.

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DPnBE/5/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.radioCheck = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        //initalize checked value of element
        element.checked = valueAccessor()();

        //attach event to handle changes
        $(element).change(function(e) {
            var item = ko.dataFor(element);
            var items = ko.contextFor(element).$parent.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                //set selected() for all items
                //true for the checked element, false for the rest
                items[i].selected(items[i] == item);                
            }
        });        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best way to match both radio buttons and checkboxes is to set the `checked` binding to an array of selected values.

For this to work, though, each radio button/checkbox needs a value, which is then what's matched against values in the array of selected values.

Based on your fiddle I came up with the following HTML:

```
<div id="two">
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <label>
            <input name="items" 
                   type="radio" 
                   name="radioItems" 
                   data-bind="value: name, 
                              checked: $root.selectedItemNames" />
            <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        </label><br/>
    </div><div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript that makes it work:

```
var viewModel2 = {
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "one",
            "selected": ko.observable(false)
        },
        {
            "name": "two",
            "selected": ko.observable(true)
        },
        {
            "name": "three",
            "selected": ko.observable(false)
        }
    ]
};

viewModel2.selectedItemNames = ko.computed(function(){
    var selectedNames = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel2.items, function(item) {
        if(item.selected()){
            selectedNames.push(item.name);
        }
    });
    return selectedNames;
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel2, document.getElementById('two'));​
```

Finally, here's a link to my forked fiddle where you can look at this code in action, along with a reworked version of the checkboxes that works in a similar manner:

Let me know if you have questions.

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/h2e9j/

Comment: sorry about that, I've updated my answer with the link that I meant to add when I posted... again, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: It's not working. "Cannot write a value to a dependentObservable unless you specify a 'write' option."

Comment: hmmm... I concentrated too much on getting the proper values & not enough on further selections :-\

I just gave this another run, but the problem I'm running into is one that's inherent to Knockout itself, specifically, when a checkbox in a checkbox group is checked/unchecked, Knockout is adding/removing the item bound to that checkbox to/from Knockout's own state variable array for managing that checkbox group, and that array manages the selected *values*.  This works nicely with strings, but it doesn't seem to play well  with objects.  That said, I've done something similar before.

Comment: In my working version, though, I had a list of selected US state abbrevations as an `observableArray`, along with a multi-select list box that was bound to a list of UsStateOption objects (abbr + name as properties).  In addition, I created a dependent observable (`ko.computed`) for selectedStates, which had a `read` function that created an array of UsStateOption objects from the list of all UsStateOptions (so that the objects matched exactly) and a `write` function that read through the selected states in value array passed in to that function and updated the observable array of state abbrs.

Comment: The jsfiddle sample is not working. Neither the checkbox list nor the radiobutton list. The checkbox list even throws a exception.